# How to prevent PHP doing auto round big float?

Tags: php

I have big float on database : `20202166.16`

When I call on PHP:

```
$num = odbc_result($sqlQuery,0);
$number = number_format($num,2,',','.');
```

I get `20.202.170,00` but I want `20.202.166,16`

Any idea how to prevent auto-rounding?

Comment: Whats the value of `$num`? As https://3v4l.org/EPBKv shows no rounding..

Comment: if I write it directly in php, the result is correct, but if I take it from the database, the result is wrong

Comment: If `var_dump($num);` still shows the wrong number then the problem is your database and/or odbc driver.

Comment: i have tried use var_dump() and still return the wrong number :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like it's not PHP based on the answers in the comments. You don't say what database you're using but taking a guess it might be MySQL?

> **Problems with Floating-Point Values**
>
> Floating-point numbers sometimes cause confusion because they are
>   approximate and not stored as exact values. A floating-point value as
>   written in an SQL statement may not be the same as the value
>   represented internally. Attempts to treat floating-point values as
>   exact in comparisons may lead to problems. They are also subject to
>   platform or implementation dependencies. The FLOAT and DOUBLE data
>   types are subject to these issues. For DECIMAL columns, MySQL performs
>   operations with a precision of 65 decimal digits, which should solve
>   most common inaccuracy problems.

Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-float.html

Try changing the column type to DECIMAL and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: actually i do not use Mysql, i am using the old database its name is sqlbase. and I try to change the float data type to double precission. and it works. thanks a lot for the answer. very helpful

Comment: Glad to hear! Please mark the answer as accepted to help future readers with the same issue.